# Toggling Material Design 2 nav menu in two separate Angular 2 component templates

Tags: html, angular, material-design, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am using Material Design 2 to toggle the left side nav:

In the header bar template:

```
<button md-icon-button (click)="leftNav.toggle()" aria-label="Menu">
        <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
 </button>
```

In the left side nav template:

```
 <md-sidenav mode="side" fxFlex="200px" #leftNav md-component-id="leftNav" opened></md-sidenav>
```

I am now trying to move the header bar and left side nav into separate custom components so that my app.template.html looks like this:

```
<div fxLayout="column">
    <header-bar></header-bar>
    <left-nav></left-nav>
</div>
```

All looks good on that page and just about everything works except the toggling of the left side nav menu, I am getting an error "cannot read property toggle of undefined". It can't find the "#leftNav" id in the left-nav component is my assumption...what is the best way in Angular 2 to go about getting these two templates to talk to each other so I can toggle the left nav component when I click on the header-bar button?

My folder structure:

```
 layout:
     header-bar:
         header-bar.html
         header-bar.ts
     left-nav:
         left-nav.html
         left-nav.ts
```

I've seen some general other examples but nothing I've been able to apply here. Happy to provide more information if needed. Thanks

Here is the html before separating into two components:

```
<div fxLayout="column">
    <!-- Header bar -->
    <!--<header-bar></header-bar>-->
 <md-toolbar color="accent" class="navbar">
          <button md-icon-button (click)="leftNav.toggle()" aria-label="Menu">
               <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
           </button>
          <span fxFlex></span>

          <button md-button [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu">
             My Account <md-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</md-icon>
          </button>
 </md-toolbar>

 <md-sidenav-container fxLayout="row">
   <md-sidenav mode="side" fxFlex="200px" #leftNav md-component-id="leftNav" opened>
    <md-nav-list>
    <md-list-item [routerLink]=" ['./dashboard'] " routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
      <md-icon>gradient</md-icon>
      <span class="padding-lr-2x">Dashboard</span>
     </md-list-item>
     <md-list-item [routerLink]=" ['./front'] " routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
      <md-icon>assignment</md-icon>
      <span class="padding-lr-2x">Form layout</span>
     </md-list-item>
     <md-list-item [routerLink]=" ['./alt'] " routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
      <md-icon>settings</md-icon>
       <span class="padding-lr-2x">Settings</span>
     </md-list-item>
   </md-nav-list>
 </md-sidenav>
 </md-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the html you were using before you created the two components?

Comment: Sorry gotta run, but I think you basically need to create an @Output parameter on `left-nav` that invokes the `side-nav` open contained within it's template

Comment: @cgatian..No problem I went ahead and added that above. In regards to your second comment, the click is coming from the header-bar component. Not sure I'm following you there